# Best case of fractional knapsack

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, knapsack-problem

the worst case running time of fractional knapsack is O(n), then what should be its best case? is it O(1), because if a weight limit is 16 and you get first item having value, is it right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> True if you assume that input is given in sorted order of value !!!

But as per the definition, the algorithm is expected to take non-sorted input too. [see this.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_knapsack_problem)

If you are considering a normal input that may or may not be sorted. Then there are two approaches to solve the problem:

1. Sort the input. which can not be less than O(n) even in best case that too if you use bubble/insertion sort. Which looks completely foolish because both of these sorting algorithms has O(n^2) avarage/worst case performance.
2. Use the [weighted medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_median) approach . That will cost you O(n) as finding the weighted median will take O(n). The code for this approach is given below.

---

**Weighted median approach for fractional knapsack:**

We will work on value per unit of item in the following code. The code will first find the middle value (i.e. mid of values per unit of items if given in sorted order) and place it in its correct position. We will use quick sort partition method for this. Once we get the middle (call it `mid`) element, following two cases need to be taken into consideration:

1. When sum of weight of all items present in the right side of `mid` is more than the value of `W`, we need to search our answer in right side of `mid`.
2. else sum all the values present in right side of mid (call it `v_left`) and search for `W-v_left` in the left side of mid (include `mid` as well).

Following is the implementation in python (Use only floating point numbers everywhere):

*Please note that i am not providing you the production level code and there are cases which will fail as well. Think about what can  cause worst case/failure for finding kth max in array (when all valules are same may be).*

```
def partition(weights,values,start,end):
    x = values[end]/weights[end]
    i = start
    for j in range(start,end):
        if values[j]/weights[j] < x:
            values[i],values[j] = values[j],values[i]
            weights[i], weights[j] = weights[j],weights[i]
            i+=1 


    values[i],values[end] = values[end],values[i]
    weights[i], weights[end] = weights[end],weights[i]

    return i


def _find_kth(weights,values,start,end,k):
    ind = partition(weights,values,start,end)
    if ind - start == k-1:
        return ind
    if ind - start > k-1:
        return _find_kth(weights,values,start,ind-1,k)
    return _find_kth(weights,values,ind+1,end,k-ind-1)

def find_kth(weights,values,k):
    return _find_kth(weights,values,0,len(weights)-1,k)


def fractional_knapsack(weights,values,w):
    if w == 0 or len(weights)==0:
        return 0

    if len(weights) == 1 and weights[0] > w:
        return w*(values[0]/weights[0])

    mid = find_kth(weights,values,len(weights)/2)

    w1 = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,weights[mid+1:])
    v1 = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, values[mid+1:])

    if(w1>w):
        return fractional_knapsack(weights[mid+1:],values[mid+1:],w)


    return v1 + fractional_knapsack(weights[:mid+1],values[:mid+1],w-w1)
```

Comment: No, if you wont do sorting and consider the second approach with weighted median, you will get O(n). As mentioned in wikipedia : by adapting an algorithm for finding weighted medians, it is possible to solve the problem in time O(n). But that would be a little complex.

Comment: ok right, but if i consider sorting approach then? which sorting algorithm is suitable and what will be the best case in this approach??

Comment: You should concentrate on avarage case. If you have an array of elements, go with quicksort and if you have linked-list of elements as input then go with merge sort.

Comment: Both quicksort and merge sort will have O(nlogn) best case. bubble and insertion sort has O(n) best case but their avarage case is O(n^2). so better use either quicksort if you have array and use merge sort if you have linked-list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128166/discussion-between-shasha99-and-rana).

Comment: I guess I was too late for chat. @Shasha99, your code is wrong. Simple testcase:
`print fractional_knapsack([10., 1.], [1., 10.], 5.)`
it prints 0.5, while the correct solution is 10.4.

Comment: @domen, I tried to implement the same approach, may be there is some bug in my code. Let me check. Will take a while.

Comment: @domen, The condition if weights[0] > w: in method fractional_knapsack() should actually be if len(weights) == 1 and weights[0] > w: . Updated the answer as well. Thanks for help. I did not test the code much, i just wanted to explain the approach. Let me know if you find any other bug.

Comment: @rana, there was some bug. I did not test my code much. It was just to show you the approach. However i modified the code now. Let me know if you find any other bug. Lets continue on chat for further discussion. Thanks.

Comment: @shasha99, thanku bro for your support, will contact you in case of any query :)

Answer (score 0):

*(Editing and rewriting the answer after discussion with @Shasha99, since I feel answers before 2016-12-06 are a bit deceiving)*

**Summary**

`O(1)` best case is possible if the items are already sorted. Otherwise best case is `O(n)`.

**Discussion**

If the items are not sorted, you need to find the best item (for the case where one item already fills the knapsack), and that alone will take `O(n)`, since you have to check all of them. Therefore, best case `O(n)`.

On the opposite end, you could have a knapsack where all the items fit. Searching for best would not be needed, but you need to *put* all of them in, so it's still `O(n)`.

---

**More analysis**

Funny enough, `O(n)` worst case does not imply items being sorted.
Apparently idea from http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/sanders/courses/algdat03/sol12.pdf paired with fast median selection algorithm (weighted medians or maybe median of medians?). Thanks to @Shasha99 for finding this algorithm.

Note that plain quickselect is `O(n)` expected, `O(n*n)` worst, but if you use median-of-medians that becomes `O(n)` worst case. The downside is quite a complicated algorithm.

I'd be interested in a working implementation of any algorithm. More sources to (hopefully simple) algorithms also wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I was not aware of O(n) algorithms for unsorted input, thanks. Do you have a nice reference for the modified weighted medians approach?

Comment: Check exercise 2 given in this assignment : http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/sanders/courses/algdat03/sol12.pdf

Comment: Exercise 2 is describing O(n) expected time (not worst case).

Comment: Yes, you should use median instead of taking uniformly distributed random variable as i have shown in code.hackerearth.com/472f7ay . finding middle element will take O(n) and then a recursion of T(n/2) will be called, which will lead to O(n) worst case case solution.

Comment: Updated my answer and included the algorithm as well.